# How to uncheck payment method radio buttons on WordPress payment page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I want the payment method radio buttons on the payment page to not be selected by default and the user to choose one of the payment methods himself.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iA3Zh.jpg)

Disable checked all radio buttons